# What's the difference between assignment and initializer list in c++?

Tags: c++

```
class a
{
private:
    const int anInt;
public:
    a() : anInt(10) {}
};
```

vs

```
class a
{
private:
    const int anInt = 10;
public:
    a() {}
};
```

What's the difference between these two? When I compile it doesn't seem to have any problem and produce the same results.

Comment: In your shown case, *both* variants are actually initialization. Even through you use `=` when done in a variable definition it's initialization and not assignment.

Comment: There is no *assignment* in the code provided.  The code is functionally identical with one another.

Comment: There's no _assignment_ in play.

Comment: C++ contains lot of ways to initialize something, you posted just two. Read docs to figure differences. <https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization>

Answer (score 0):

it's quite different.
The Initializer List is used to initialize a class's data members. At some time after the variable is created, 'Assignment' gives that variable a value.

Answer (score 0):

There could be other differences, but the first and main difference between the two is that initialization gives a variable an initial value at the time it is created. On the other hand, assignment gives a variable a value at some point after the variable is created.

Comment: Except that `const int anInt = 10;` is not an assignment in any context.